# WPF цветовая схема

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Доброго дня! Хочу сделать разделение ресурсов между сборками, так как показано здесь: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level10/10_7.php

Применить ресурс в окне WPF приложения получается, а если это окно у меня в library то ресурс не применяется.

> The resource "`{x:Static res:CustomResources.MainBackgroundColorKey}`"
>   could not be resolved.

Прошу помочь решить проблему или посоветуйте другой путь организации хранения цветовых схем приложения.

Comment: ...дайте больше информации, пока сложно понять что вы сделали не так. Могу только ссылок по теме накидать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224864/the-resource-x-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: У меня 2 библиотеки, одна CustomControlLibrary хранит ресурсы (SolidColorBrush) , а во второй WPF окно. Вот и хочу ресурсы из одной либы применять к окну в другой.

Comment: Покажите строку `xmlns` подключения ресурса в проект, а так же к окну. Т.к. не понятно откуда вы взяли этот самый `res:SomeStaticObject`

Comment: Как я добавляю ресурсы в проект показано по ссылке которую привел выше. Вопрос в том, что в wpf app все без проблем, а если wpf окно в либе то ресурс не применяется.

Comment: xmlns:res="clr-namespace:ResourceLibrary;assembly=ResourceLibrary"